# How can I pickle cookies into an existing list?

Tags: python, cookies, pickle

I'm trying to pickle some cookies in to a existing pickled list but I keep getting an error.

```
twitter_loggins = []
pickle_path = "/home/ro/A_Python_Scripts/twitter/twitter2/twitter_loggins.pkl"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://twitter.com")
cookies = []

email = raw_input("Email used?")
cookies1 = driver.get_cookies
cookie = [email, cookies1]
cookies.append(cookie)

if os.path.exists(pickle_path):
    with open(pickle_path, 'rb') as loggins:
        cookies1 = pickle.load(loggins)
        for cookie in cookies1:
            cookies.append(cookie)

with open(pickle_path, 'wb') as file1:
    pickle.dump(cookies, file1)
```

My working code that pickles the cookies.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://twitter.com")
continu = raw_input("Press Enter when you've logged in")
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies() , open("/home/ro/A_Python_Scripts/twitter/twitter_loggins.pkl", "wb"))
```

I get the folowing traceback error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "save_cookies.py", line 40, in <module>
    cookies1 = pickle.load(loggins)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

So I need the pickled file to look like this [['email1','cookie1','cookie2'],['email2','cookie1','cookie2']]

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in the first script at `cookies1 = driver.get_cookies` where you simply reference the method but don't call it (it needs to be `cookies1 = driver.get_cookies()`). You open the file `"wb"` which truncates the file but since the function object is not picklable, an exception is raised and you have an empty file. On the future iterations, `pickle.load` fails because the file is empty.